# Why won't [ ] brackets work when dereferencing a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, dereference

If I have a std::vector, I can access a member because the square bracket operator is overloaded in the vector class. If I have a pointer to a vector, I can dereference the pointer and use this operator. But with the arrow -> operator it won't let me use it.  Example:

```
 // Excuse the UB here, it's just for illustration
    std::vector<int> myVector;    
    std::vector<int>* pToVector;
    myVector[4] = 0;                   // Works fine
    (*pToVector)[4] = 0;               // Works fine
    pToVector->[4] = 0;                // Doesn't work
    (pToVector->)[4] = 0;              // Doesn't work
```

Seeing as though the -> arrow operator dereferences the pointer, is there a reason not to expect that this would work? Or is it just one of those things about the language?

Thanks.

Comment: The first 2 assignments may appear to work but you are accessing outside the container boundaries which is UB. You need to declare it like this `std::vector<int> myVector(5)` which will allocate the necessary space to access `myVector[4]`  The latter two are illegal constructs

Comment: It is incorrect syntax. Arrows operator gives you *objec. structure so pToVector->[4] = 0 similar to *pToVector.[4] = 0. Neither this line(pToVector->)[4] nor this pToVector->[4] will not work

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? `a->b` means `(*a).b`. So, `a->[b]` could mean `(*a).[]` which makes no sense.

Comment: `->[4]` is simply not grammatical. this! likejust:sENTECE?

Comment: Note that `myVector.[4]` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<int> myVector;    
std::vector<int>* pToVector;
myVector[4] = 0;                   // Works fine.
(*pToVector)[4] = 0;               // Works fine
pToVector->[4] = 0;                // Doesn't work
(pToVector->)[4] = 0;              // Doesn't work
```

If you must use a pointer to an object to access an overloaded operator of the object's class, you will have to call it explicitly.

```
pToVector->operator[](4)
```

... By the way, Accessing an index outside `myVector.size()` is Undefined Behavior. This includes the statements with the comment annotation in your code about `// Works fine`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for the second two lines would be:

```
(*pToVector)[4] = 0; 
//dereference the pointer and then call operator[] on the object returned by the dereference
```

You could use the `->` operator to access regular member functions like this:

```
pToVector->size();
```

Technically you could try yo call the `operator[]` by name but it is more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `[]` is an operator, and the short operator syntax does not require or allow member access operators. This applies to both member access operators `.` and `->`, which makes sense because the latter is just shorthand for `(*a).b`.

E.g. all disallowed `a. & b`, `a->^b`

Technically, it also applies to the rarer `.*` and `->*`. Note that the latter is **not** `->` followed by `operator*`, but a pointer to member pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

The `->` operator does not just dereference, it also accesses a member. You are accessing an element<sup>*</sup>, not a member. `->` could have been defined to allow that, but wasn't.

<sub><sup>*</sup> To be more precise, a vector is letting you access an object as if it were an element of an array, but it doesn't change the syntax.</sub>

Comment: "element" versus "member" ? C++ has no such difference; the terms are used interchangeably.

Comment: @MSalters Do you have examples of where the C++ standard refers to class elements or to array members? I'm not finding them, but it's possible I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @hvd: I was a bit misled by reading your statement as "`->` is accessing an element", but never mind. C++ doesn't formally define _element_ and the Standard only has `element_type` in the index, but 1.8/2 leaves fairly little doubt. That said, in this question `[ ]` does not access an array element,, but refers to the member function `operator[ ]`. Same tokens, different meaning.

Comment: @MSalters Fair point, an overloaded `operator[]` means it's a class only pretending to have elements. Will edit, thanks.

Comment: I like to listen their  experiences. Nonetheless, I fed up with obsessions of the gaffers here @hvd

Answer (score 0):

`->` operator is replacement for dot operator, except it dereferences a pointer first. It is used to access attributes(members and functions). For your operation, `operator[]` is the attribute. So, `pToVector->operator[](4)` is applied to `(*pToVector)[4] = 0`

Comment: `->` is not restricted to data members, it also works with member functions. And clearly `operator[ ]` is a function member, not data.

Comment: `attribute` word is more suitable. But I could mean both members and methods while saying data field @MSalters

Comment: `attribute` is not a keyword, and [attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) are something completely different. Also, "members and methods" makes little sense; methods are a subset of members. (namely member functions).

Comment: I meant "word". I wonder why old guys like you are obsessed with the stuff. @MSalters. En passant, _`a nod is as good as a wink to a blind horse`_

Comment: If you think we're obsessed, meet compiler writers. We're being consistent because these words have specific meanings, and different words have different meanings. For instance, **because** `main` is no_ a keyword, you can have a data member called `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the square brackets dereference the pointer, so you ended up dereferencing twice there.

ptoVector[4] I think would have worked and been sufficient since the square brackets do a dereference for you.